# Cannot read properties of undefined (reading '3') when trying to use (click) events in Angular

Tags: javascript, html, angular, typescript

> **UPDATE:** Someone suggested building with optimization turned off to see clearer errors, and doing that appears to have actually fixed the entire thing. Everything works fine now, but it's also (significantly) larger now since it's no longer optimized. If anyone has ideas as to why optimization would break the site or how to make it not do that, let me know.

I'm trying to make an Angular site that can search for data based on a number of input fields. When I run the site locally using `ng serve` it works fine, but when I compile it with `ng build` and host the resulting files using a Docker container, it throws the error `Cannot read properties of undefined (reading '3')` in the console and fails to properly load the site.

Commenting out the two buttons at the bottom of the HTML template seems to make the error go away, and the page loads properly (apart from lacking buttons) so I'm thinking the problem might be something to do with the `(click)` event binding. Any idea how I can fix this?

The typescript file, `search.component.ts`:

```js
import { Component } from '@angular/core';
import { SearchEntry } from '../student.service';
import { StudentService } from '../student.service';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-search',
  templateUrl: './search.component.html',
  styleUrl: './search.component.css'
})
export class SearchComponent {
  constructor(private studentService: StudentService) {}
  searchParams: SearchEntry = {
    lifetimeID: '', uni: '', pid: '', lastName: '', firstName: '', gradYear: '',
    status: '', entryTerm: '', termNumber: '', program: '', cluster: ''
  };
  searchResults: SearchEntry[] = [];

  searchStudents(params: SearchEntry): void {
    const resultObs = this.studentService.searchStudents(params);
    resultObs.subscribe(results => this.searchResults = results);
  }

  clearFields(): void {
    this.searchParams = {
      lifetimeID: '', uni: '', pid: '', lastName: '', firstName: '', gradYear: '',
      status: '', entryTerm: '', termNumber: '', program: '', cluster: ''
    };
  }
}
```

The HTML template, `search.component.html`:

```html
<div class="wrapper">
    <h4>Search for Entries</h4>
    <input [(ngModel)]="searchParams.lifetimeID" placeholder="Lifetime ID"><br>
    <input [(ngModel)]="searchParams.uni" placeholder="UNI"><br>
    <input [(ngModel)]="searchParams.pid" placeholder="PID"><br>
    <input [(ngModel)]="searchParams.lastName" placeholder="Last Name"><br>
    <input [(ngModel)]="searchParams.firstName" placeholder="First Name"><br>
    <input [(ngModel)]="searchParams.gradYear" placeholder="Grad Year"><br>
    <input [(ngModel)]="searchParams.status" placeholder="Status"><br>
    <input [(ngModel)]="searchParams.entryTerm" placeholder="Entry Term"><br>
    <input [(ngModel)]="searchParams.cluster" placeholder="Cluster"><br>
    <input [(ngModel)]="searchParams.program" placeholder="Program"><br>
    <input [(ngModel)]="searchParams.termNumber" placeholder="Term Number"><br>
    <button type="button" (click)="searchStudents(searchParams)">Search</button>
    <button type="button" (click)="clearFields()">Clear</button><br>
</div>

<app-student-list [results]="searchResults"></app-student-list>
```

The `app-student-list` component referenced on the last line of the HTML template appears to work fine on its own, so I didn't include the code for it.

Comment: What happens inside the `click` functions? Do you have an idea where the `3` might come from?

Comment: usually such error appears when you are trying to get 3rd element of array, but array is undefined: `myarray[3]` where myarray is not defined yet. You can also try to build the app without optimization: `ng build --prod --optimization=false` to see where exact something goes wrong

Comment: I tried building it with `--optimization false`, and that build works totally fine - so it seems like somehow the optimization is breaking something?

Comment: I have the feeling it has to do with the statement 'searchStudents(searchParams)'. How your "button" has access to the context in which "searchParams" is available. Normally, you can do such calls if the function argument is a variable available in the context of your template. For example, you get such variables using "ngFor". What would you get if you console.log "searchParams" when the method is being executed?

Comment: The page doesn't even get to load the buttons when the error occurs, so I don't have a chance to click one and see what the function does. I tried removing the click event bindings, leaving buttons that don't do anything, but that didn't seem to change anything.